# Keep track on an iframe in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, intervals

I have an iframe in jquery and I want to track it (keep track of it and when it changes, or when it's value is changing - do something)

The only solution I thought of so far was doing this with setInterval that checks every second did the iframe change.

> > $(function(){
> >     setInterval(function(){ if $("#myiframe").html()=="1" { alert('changed'); },1000)
> >     });

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

`<iframe onload="iframeLoad();" src="...">`

Elsewhere define the function `iframeLoad()`, and it will run every time a new page finishes loading inside the iframe.

Comment: Problem is - iframe value changes using AJAX, so it finishes loading before it really loads my content.

Answer (score 0):

You can track the onLoad event on the iframe, which will be fired every time the iframe changes location.Sample:

```
<iframe src="http://www.blahhh.com/" onLoad="doSomething();"></iframe>
```

**NOTE: This will only work with same origin domains, of course!**